# Clean URL htaccess - (?p=1)

Tags: .htaccess, url

How can I Rewrite with htaccess file the url
http://www.example.com/index.php?p=1 
So it will look like this:
http://www.example.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!
I have several pages, 12 to be correct :)
and the url ends with ?p=1, ?p=2, ?p=3, ?p=4, ...

Comment: Last question I hope :)
So if I want to create "clean url's" on all site I just write this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?gallery.php$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?contact.php$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]

Comment: @KatiaGavrilov yes, this will work. If you have a lot of urls, you might look at something more generic. let me know